# Java synchronizing with thread using getState method

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, java-threads

I have two classes:

- **TestClass**, a class that uses user input via Scanner

```java
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("1: ");
        String one = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("2: ");
        String two = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("3: ");
        String three = scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

- **Test**, a class that provides fake input to the **TestClass** to test it

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PipedOutputStream inputSimulator = new PipedOutputStream();
        PrintStream inputProvider = new PrintStream(inputSimulator);
        System.setIn(new BufferedInputStream(new PipedInputStream(inputSimulator)));

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> TestClass.main(new String[]{}));
        thread.start();

        while (thread.getState() != Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING) ;
        inputProvider.println("One given");
        System.out.println("One given");

        while (thread.getState() != Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING) ;
        inputProvider.println("Two given");
        System.out.println("Two given");

        while (thread.getState() != Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING) ;
        inputProvider.println("Three given");
        System.out.println("Three given");
    }
}
```

I cannot get the **Test** class to synchronize with the **TestClass**. By synchronize, I mean that if I want this to be printed in the console:

```
1: One given
2: Two given
3: Three given
```

However, I get:

```
1: One given
Two given
Three given
2: 3:
```

I used the `while` loop to check that the thread's scanner is currently waiting for input. But, after the first input, such checking mechanism does not work. I need to do this without editing the **TestClass**. What is a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically relying on timing with threads is a **really bad idea**, however based on your comments and constrains the best that I could come up with was using `Thread.sleep` like so:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        PipedOutputStream inputSimulator = new PipedOutputStream();
        PrintStream inputProvider = new PrintStream(inputSimulator);
        System.setIn(new BufferedInputStream(new PipedInputStream(inputSimulator)));

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> TestClass.main(new String[]{}));
        thread.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        while (thread.getState() != Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING) ;
        inputProvider.println("One given");
        System.out.println("One given");

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        while (thread.getState() != Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING) ;
        inputProvider.println("Two given");
        System.out.println("Two given");

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        while (thread.getState() != Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING) ;
        inputProvider.println("Three given");
        System.out.println("Three given");
    }
}
```

Probably, for your context you will have to add additional checks and so on.

Comment: It also looks like an undocumented implementation detail that a thread reading from a `PipedInputStream` enters the `TIMED_WAITING` state at all (instead of, e.g.  `WAITING`).

Comment: Yep, this is clearly a no no in production, but with the constraint  of not being able to modify the TestClass, I do not see a different way of solving

Comment: Well, you could replace the `PipedOutputStream`/`PipedInputStream` combo by something that supports querying how much of the previously written data has been read already (or even supports waiting for it). In fact, just passing a very small buffer size to the `PipedInputStream​`’s constructor will already have the effect of each `inputProvider.println(…)` waiting for the receiver. If that’s all the OP wants, nothing more is needed. Of course, the contradicting `BufferedInputStream` should not be used then.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the suggestion I will have look after work.